# How can I set 'absolute' or 'fixed' with width: 100% to its parent div not the window size?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to have a banner like below
[image]

using 'absolute' or 'fixed'.

However, it becomes like this when I tried with 'left: 0 right: 0 top: 0'
[image]

or with width '100%, then it pushes the right. How can I set 'A' like in the first picture? I don't want to use relative or static since it pushes the content downward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with `fixed`, but you can set the parent div (the black box in your example) to have `position: relative;` and that will make the `absolute` positioned child position itself according to the parent div.

**Why is this?**

> Absolute - the element is positioned absolutely to its first positioned parent. -- [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute)

What this means is that the `absolute` positioned element will position itself according to the nearest ancestor with an assigned `position`, besides `static`.

I hope this is clear enough, but let me know if it's not.